# Android ViewPager on full screen

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fullscreen

I have the following android layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#3f5561"
android:id="@+id/MainLayout">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabs" />

<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
    app:pstsTextAllCaps="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="#a97878"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

[image: That's what it looks like]

As you can see, the ViewPager has grey color around it, which is the color of the MainLayout. My question is, how can i set the ViewPager on fullscreen(Without the MainLayout around it). For example like YouTube, PlayStore and ect. That's how i want it to look[image]

How can i possibly do that? Example will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding left, right and top padding to the container, that's why you are getting the grey area. There is no bottom padding so bottom part is ok.

Remove these line from your `RelativeLayout`

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Answer (score 1):

you added padding that's why it's showing MainLayout around it, remove padding to apply ViewPager to whole screen

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```